# Highlight answers containing links in the "answers" tab of users

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, moderator-tools

When dealing with users who have some legit posts but also spamvertise their service it would be helpful to quickly see which of their answers contain a link and which don't. Probably not too useful for non-moderators though...

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you can pull up all of their link-containing answers using the [search query `user:147015 is:answer url:"*"`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A147015+is%3Aanswer+url%3A%27*%22) (using the current search, at least).